# Text width based on text length in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have this *ListView.generator* that returns such *Containers*

```dart
Container(
  child: Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        child: null,
        width: 10,
        height: 10,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: social[i].color,
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
        ),
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 7, top: 1,),
      ),
      Text(
        social[i].name, 
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white, 
          fontFamily: 'Muli', 
          fontSize: 24.0, 
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700
        ),
      )
    ],
  ), 
  width: social[i].name.length * 16.0,
)
```

Right know I'm making use of width to set it based on text length but it's giving me and inadequate result as spacing between twitter and instagram is bigger than it should be.

[image: inadequate result]

The result I want being this with an even space between them.
[image: adequate result]

A *Wrap* widget with spacing set to even wouldn't help as I want this list to have a full width of the user resolution and to be aligned to the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly`  for Row element like

```
Container(
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        child: null,
        width: 10,
        height: 10,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: social[i].color,
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
        ),
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 7, top: 1,),
      ),
      Text(
        social[i].name, 
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white, 
          fontFamily: 'Muli', 
          fontSize: 24.0, 
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700
        ),
      )
    ],
  ), 
  width: social[i].name.length * 16.0,
)
```

In case you want to know more about it. https://medium.com/jlouage/flutter-row-column-cheat-sheet-78c38d242041 you can check this article. I found it really helpful.